# Hadoop shuffle/merge time: average vs. total

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Hadoop outputs the following statistics:

- average map time
- average reduce time
- average shuffle time
- average merge time

The total map and reduce time can be obtained by multiplying the number of completed maps/reduces with these averages. But how can the total shuffle/merge time be obtained? Or: how is the average shuffle time calculated?

Answer (score 1):

**Average Map Time** = Total time taken by all Map tasks/ Count of Map Tasks

**Average Reduce Time** = Total time taken by all Reduce tasks/Count of Reduce tasks

**Average Merge time** = Average of (attempt.sortFinishTime - attempt.shuffleFinishTime)

In **Shuffle** phase, intermediate data, which was generated by Map tasks is directed to the right reducers. The Shuffle phase assigns keys to reducers & 
sends all values of a particular key to the right reducer.

Sorting also happens in this phase before sending output values to Reducer.

The shuffle phase involves transfer of data across the network from Map nodes.

From [Apache link](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html)

**Shuffle**

Input to the Reducer is the sorted output of the mappers. In this phase the framework fetches the relevant partition of the output of all the mappers, via HTTP.

**Sort**

The framework groups Reducer inputs by keys (since different mappers may have output the same key) in this stage.

The shuffle and sort phases occur simultaneously; while map-outputs are being fetched they are merged.

Hadoop framework will execute these two phases : **shuffling & sorting**

Comment: Thanks! But how can these numbers be converted from average to totals? Multiplying by number of reduce tasks?

Comment: Map and Reduce times can be multiplied for map and reduce functions. But I doubt about merge and shuffle times which have been executed by framework itself.